# How to print the meaning of word only while using the Oxford API in Python?

Tags: python, json, api

I got the json file by calling the Oxford dictionary API. I want to find the meaning of the word only but it is giving me all the information of the word. The meaning is actually DEFINITION in this file.  How can I extract the DEFINITION part from this json file using Python?

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "provider": "Oxford University Press"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "help",
            "language": "en",
            "lexicalEntries": [
                {
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "etymologies": [
                                "Old English helpan (verb), help (noun), of Germanic origin; related to Dutch helpen and German helfen"
                            ],
                            "grammaticalFeatures": [
                                {
                                    "text": "Transitive",
                                    "type": "Subcategorization"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": "Present",
                                    "type": "Tense"
                                }
                            ],
                            "homographNumber": "000",
                            "senses": [
                                {
                                    "***definitions***": [
                                        "make it easier or possible for (someone) to do something by offering them one's services or resources"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "the teenager helped out in the corner shop"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "she helped him find a buyer"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "they helped her with domestic chores"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.006",
                                    "short_definitions": [
                                        "assist someone to do something"
                                    ],
                                    "subsenses": [
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "improve (a situation or problem); be of benefit to"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "legislation to fit all new cars with catalytic converters will help"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "text": "upbeat comments about prospects helped confidence"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.012",
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "improve situation"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "help",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.003"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "assist (someone) to move"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "I helped her up"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.013",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "with object and adverbial of direction",
                                                    "type": "grammaticalNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "assist someone to move"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "assist someone to put on or take off (a garment)"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "she would help him off with his coat"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.014",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "\"help someone on/off with\"",
                                                    "type": "wordFormNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "assist someone with garment"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "thesaurusLinks": [
                                        {
                                            "entry_id": "help",
                                            "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.001"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "serve someone with (food or drink)"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "may I help you to some more meat?"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "she helped herself to a biscuit"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.017",
                                    "notes": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "\"help someone to\"",
                                            "type": "wordFormNote"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "short_definitions": [
                                        "serve someone with food or drink"
                                    ],
                                    "subsenses": [
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "take something without permission"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "he helped himself to the wages she had brought home"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.018",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "\"help oneself\"",
                                                    "type": "wordFormNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "take something without permission"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "help_oneself_to",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.006"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "cannot or could not avoid"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "he couldn't help laughing"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "I'm sorry to put you to any inconvenience, but it can't be helped"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.020",
                                    "notes": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "\"can/could not help\"",
                                            "type": "wordFormNote"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "short_definitions": [
                                        "cannot or could not avoid"
                                    ],
                                    "subsenses": [
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "cannot or could not stop oneself from doing something"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "she couldn't help herself; she burst into tears"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.021",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "\"can/could not help oneself\"",
                                                    "type": "wordFormNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "cannot or could not stop oneself"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "thesaurusLinks": [
                                        {
                                            "entry_id": "cannot_help",
                                            "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.005"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "language": "en",
                    "lexicalCategory": "Verb",
                    "pronunciations": [
                        {
                            "audioFile": "http://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/help_gb_1.mp3",
                            "dialects": [
                                "British English"
                            ],
                            "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                            "phoneticSpelling": "h?lp"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "help"
                },
                {
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "grammaticalFeatures": [
                                {
                                    "text": "Mass",
                                    "type": "Countability"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": "Singular",
                                    "type": "Number"
                                }
                            ],
                            "homographNumber": "001",
                            "senses": [
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "the action of helping someone to do something"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "I asked for help from my neighbours"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.023",
                                    "short_definitions": [
                                        "action of helping"
                                    ],
                                    "subsenses": [
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "the fact of being useful"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "the skimpy manual isn't much help for beginners"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.025",
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "fact of being useful"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "usefulness",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0015781.001"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "a person or thing that helps"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "he was a great help"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "text": "she's been given financial help with travel"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.026",
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "person or thing that helps"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "backup",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0001080.001"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "a domestic employee"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "she has taught herself to cook since the defection of the last of the village helps"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "text": "the help cleaned up the leftover food and half-drunk cocktails"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.027",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "count noun",
                                                    "type": "grammaticalNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "domestic employee"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "help",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.009"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "giving assistance to a computer user in the form of displayed instructions"
                                            ],
                                            "domains": [
                                                "Computing"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "a help menu"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.030",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "as modifier",
                                                    "type": "grammaticalNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "giving assistance to computer user"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "thesaurusLinks": [
                                        {
                                            "entry_id": "help",
                                            "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.007"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "language": "en",
                    "lexicalCategory": "Noun",
                    "pronunciations": [
                        {
                            "audioFile": "http://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/help_gb_1.mp3",
                            "dialects": [
                                "British English"
                            ],
                            "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                            "phoneticSpelling": "h?lp"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "help"
                },
                {
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "homographNumber": "002",
                            "senses": [
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "used as an appeal for urgent assistance"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "Help! I'm drowning!"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.033",
                                    "short_definitions": [
                                        "appeal for urgent assistance"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "language": "en",
                    "lexicalCategory": "Interjection",
                    "pronunciations": [
                        {
                            "audioFile": "http://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/help_gb_1.mp3",
                            "dialects": [
                                "British English"
                            ],
                            "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                            "phoneticSpelling": "h?lp"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "help"
                }
            ],
            "type": "headword",
            "word": "help"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which definition?

Comment: "***definitions***": [
                                        "make it easier or possible for (someone) to do something by offering them one's services or resources"
                                    ],

Comment: print(r.text['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['definitions'][0])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: use `r.data` not `r.text`

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: iwhen i type print(type(r.text) it shows   <class 'str'> . I dont know why . i tried the r.data but it shows error

Comment: please respond to my answer not to your question. What error?

Comment: error is     print(r.data['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['definitions'][0])
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Ok, my apologies, use `r.json` I failed to remember response has `json` attribute not `data`

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: now it shows the error    print(r.json['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['***definitions***'][0])
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: smh Use `r.json()`.

Comment: I did it but still its not working as showing the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API result is in the form of nested dictionary and lists.

If you don't want to use an API filter you need to `import json` and load in the form of a Python object.

```
y = json.loads(<filename>.text) #filename should be the file where your json is saved
y = y["results"][0]["lexicalEntries"][0]["entries"][0]["senses"][0]["definitions"]

for definition in y:
    print (definition)
    print("\n")
```

The code above should print all the definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into looping through each sublist and finding matches and such, you can just use the following:

```
text['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['***definitions***'][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the filter API in order to get only the fields you are interested in.
See https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation#!/Dictionary32entries/get_entries_source_lang_word_id_filters

See the code below in order to see how the filter is used

```
import requests
import os
import pprint

app_id = os.getenv('OXFORD_APP_ID', None)
if not app_id:
    raise Exception('Oxford App ID must be provided')

app_key = os.getenv('OXFORD_APP_KEY', None)
if not app_key:
    raise Exception('Oxford App key must be provided')

# This is the part you need to play with
# See https://api-blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2018/02/23/making-sense-of-senses-wordlist-endpoint/ for more info
QUERY_FILTER = 'grammaticalFeatures=singular,past;lexicalCategory=noun'

LANGUAGE = 'en'

WORD_TO_SEARCH = 'dog'

url = 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/{}/{}/{}'.format(LANGUAGE, WORD_TO_SEARCH, QUERY_FILTER)

r = requests.get(url, headers={'app_id': app_id, 'app_key': app_key})

if r.status_code == 200:
    result = r.json()
    pprint.pprint(result)
else:
    print('There was a problem calling oxford API. Status code is {}'.format(r.status_code))
```

A version with no filter.

```
import requests
import os

app_id = os.getenv('OXFORD_APP_ID', None)
if not app_id:
    raise Exception('Oxford App ID must be provided')

app_key = os.getenv('OXFORD_APP_KEY', None)
if not app_key:
    raise Exception('Oxford App key must be provided')


def get_oxford_word_definitions(word, lang='en'):
    r = requests.get('https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/{}/{}'.format(lang, word),
                     headers={'app_id': app_id, 'app_key': app_key})
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return True, r.json()["results"][0]["lexicalEntries"][0]["entries"][0]["senses"][0]["definitions"]
    else:
        return False, 'There was a problem calling oxford API. Status code is {}'.format(r.status_code)


ok, definitions_or_error_msg = get_oxford_word_definitions('dog')
if ok:
    print(definitions_or_error_msg)
else:
    print('Failed to query API. {}'.format(definitions_or_error_msg))
```

Comment: can you provide a code for the same . I am new to these and i don't know how to do the same . it will be very helpful if you tell me the code

Comment: I have submitted working code. You will have to play with the filter argument. You can drop an email to the API team and ask them if you can not make it work. api@oxforddictionaries.com

Comment: QUERY_FILTER = 'grammaticalFeatures=singular,past;lexicalCategory=noun'   here in querry_filter i am writing definitions but still it is not comming and showing the error

Comment: I am not sure which error you are talking about. I am adding a version with no filter. The code is wrapped under a function so the caller just gets back the list of definitions.