# How to extract meaning of the word using the Oxford API in Python?

Tags: python, json

I am using the Oxford api to get the meaning of a word in Python. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
app_id = 'My-App-ID'
app_key = 'My-App-Key'
language = 'en'
word_id = 'help'
url = 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/'+ language + '/'+ word_id.lower()
#url Normalized frequency
urlFR = 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/stats/frequency/word/'  + language + '/?corpus=nmc&lemma=' + word_id.lower()
r = requests.get(url, headers = {'app_id' : app_id, 'app_key' : app_key})
#print("code {}\n".format(r.status_code))
print("text \n" + r.text)
#print("json \n" + json.dumps(r.json()))
```

And the output I got is following

```
text 
{
    "metadata": {
        "provider": "Oxford University Press"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "help",
            "language": "en",
            "lexicalEntries": [
                {
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "etymologies": [
                                "Old English helpan (verb), help (noun), of Germanic origin; related to Dutch helpen and German helfen"
                            ],
                            "grammaticalFeatures": [
                                {
                                    "text": "Transitive",
                                    "type": "Subcategorization"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": "Present",
                                    "type": "Tense"
                                }
                            ],
                            "homographNumber": "000",
                            "senses": [
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "make it easier or possible for (someone) to do something by offering them one's services or resources"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "the teenager helped out in the corner shop"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "she helped him find a buyer"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "they helped her with domestic chores"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.006",
                                    "short_definitions": [
                                        "assist someone to do something"
                                    ],
                                    "subsenses": [
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "improve (a situation or problem); be of benefit to"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "legislation to fit all new cars with catalytic converters will help"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "text": "upbeat comments about prospects helped confidence"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.012",
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "improve situation"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "help",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.003"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "assist (someone) to move"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "I helped her up"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.013",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "with object and adverbial of direction",
                                                    "type": "grammaticalNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "assist someone to move"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "assist someone to put on or take off (a garment)"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "she would help him off with his coat"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.014",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "\"help someone on/off with\"",
                                                    "type": "wordFormNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "assist someone with garment"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "thesaurusLinks": [
                                        {
                                            "entry_id": "help",
                                            "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.001"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "serve someone with (food or drink)"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "may I help you to some more meat?"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "she helped herself to a biscuit"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.017",
                                    "notes": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "\"help someone to\"",
                                            "type": "wordFormNote"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "short_definitions": [
                                        "serve someone with food or drink"
                                    ],
                                    "subsenses": [
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "take something without permission"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "he helped himself to the wages she had brought home"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.018",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "\"help oneself\"",
                                                    "type": "wordFormNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "take something without permission"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "help_oneself_to",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.006"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "cannot or could not avoid"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "he couldn't help laughing"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "I'm sorry to put you to any inconvenience, but it can't be helped"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.020",
                                    "notes": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "\"can/could not help\"",
                                            "type": "wordFormNote"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "short_definitions": [
                                        "cannot or could not avoid"
                                    ],
                                    "subsenses": [
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "cannot or could not stop oneself from doing something"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "she couldn't help herself; she burst into tears"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.021",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "\"can/could not help oneself\"",
                                                    "type": "wordFormNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "cannot or could not stop oneself"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "thesaurusLinks": [
                                        {
                                            "entry_id": "cannot_help",
                                            "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.005"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "language": "en",
                    "lexicalCategory": "Verb",
                    "pronunciations": [
                        {
                            "audioFile": "http://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/help_gb_1.mp3",
                            "dialects": [
                                "British English"
                            ],
                            "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                            "phoneticSpelling": "hɛlp"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "help"
                },
                {
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "grammaticalFeatures": [
                                {
                                    "text": "Mass",
                                    "type": "Countability"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": "Singular",
                                    "type": "Number"
                                }
                            ],
                            "homographNumber": "001",
                            "senses": [
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "the action of helping someone to do something"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "I asked for help from my neighbours"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.023",
                                    "short_definitions": [
                                        "action of helping"
                                    ],
                                    "subsenses": [
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "the fact of being useful"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "the skimpy manual isn't much help for beginners"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.025",
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "fact of being useful"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "usefulness",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0015781.001"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "a person or thing that helps"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "he was a great help"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "text": "she's been given financial help with travel"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.026",
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "person or thing that helps"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "backup",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0001080.001"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "a domestic employee"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "she has taught herself to cook since the defection of the last of the village helps"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "text": "the help cleaned up the leftover food and half-drunk cocktails"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.027",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "count noun",
                                                    "type": "grammaticalNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "domestic employee"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "help",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.009"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "giving assistance to a computer user in the form of displayed instructions"
                                            ],
                                            "domains": [
                                                "Computing"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "a help menu"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.030",
                                            "notes": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "as modifier",
                                                    "type": "grammaticalNote"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "giving assistance to computer user"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "thesaurusLinks": [
                                        {
                                            "entry_id": "help",
                                            "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006913.007"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "language": "en",
                    "lexicalCategory": "Noun",
                    "pronunciations": [
                        {
                            "audioFile": "http://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/help_gb_1.mp3",
                            "dialects": [
                                "British English"
                            ],
                            "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                            "phoneticSpelling": "hɛlp"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "help"
                },
                {
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "homographNumber": "002",
                            "senses": [
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "used as an appeal for urgent assistance"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "Help! I'm drowning!"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0460970.033",
                                    "short_definitions": [
                                        "appeal for urgent assistance"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "language": "en",
                    "lexicalCategory": "Interjection",
                    "pronunciations": [
                        {
                            "audioFile": "http://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/help_gb_1.mp3",
                            "dialects": [
                                "British English"
                            ],
                            "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                            "phoneticSpelling": "hɛlp"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "help"
                }
            ],
            "type": "headword",
            "word": "help"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here the word id "help" whose information is shown in the output. I want to extract the **definition** part only. See below:

```
"definitions": [
                                    "make it easier or possible for (someone) to do something by offering them one's services or resources"
                                ],
```

You can see there is a definition part in the output. How to do this in Python? There are so many definitions available, I just want the first one.

Comment: This appears to be much the same as your prior question. Is it different, and if so, in what way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the meaning of word only while using the Oxford API in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965973/how-to-print-the-meaning-of-word-only-while-using-the-oxford-api-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

```
y = json.loads(r.text) #filename should be the file where your json is saved
y = y["results"][0]["lexicalEntries"][0]["entries"][0]["senses"][0]["definitions"]

for definition in y:
    print (definition)
    print("\n")
```

Comment: This appears to be a direct copy+paste from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54966956/472495) given to your previous question. What is the purpose of (re)posting it?

Comment: Two things: 1. Please describe what the code does, don't provide just code. This helps other in learning. 2. If you copy (parts) of other answers or questions you need to include a link as reference.